# How do I fix this function syntax?

Tags: python, django, syntax

Iv'e tried searching up the problem to no avail, so I chose to come on stack overflow to ask this problem.

```
def Year(2015):
          ^
    Syntax Right here

    Year = 2015
    return Year

Year = '2015'
print(Year)
```

Comment: `def Year(2015):` does not make much sense. A function takes *parameters*, `2015` is not an identifier, it is an integer literal.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me; otherwise review ***[4.6. Defining Functions in The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)***.

Comment: And also welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you intending to do, but what you seem to intend to do is to define `Year(...)` as function. Well, in Python when defining function you need to put in brackets a **parameter** that it would be used somewhere inside the function.
 `Def Year(Year_Param): # Do stuff return Year_Param`

So in this is how a function is defined in Python, where Year_Param is a Parameter that you give when calling the function Year().
If what you are looking for is that the function Year uses default value for a Parameter in case it is called without Parameters, then you shoud write `def Year(Year_Param = 2015): # Your stuffs here`
In this case, if you call **Year()** like this without putting anything in middle of the brackets it would automatically be like **Year(2015)**